# Error when run ios project, main.dart not changes and keep default code

Tags: ios, flutter

Error when run ios project, main.dart not changes and keep default code, but after i do hot restart, the app run perfectly and compile the code that i already edit at main.dart.

this is my main.dart

```
void _enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop() {
  if (!kIsWeb && (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux)) {
    debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;
  }
}

void main() {
  // ignore: invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member
  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
  _enablePlatformOverrideForDesktop();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

This only happen when i run the project, what is the problem i really dont know, do anyone know how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: are you using VS Code on windows ?

Comment: no, i'm using mac

Comment: try the posted solution and let me know if that works, because that worked for me

Comment: i tried it, but not working, i dont know how, but my app executing another main.dart project, is it because i copying ios folder from another project and paste in my current project ?

Comment: try flutter pub cache repair

Comment: still same, app run main.dart default code, after i hot reload the app run perfectly.

Comment: I realized that this problem was caused by copying another App.framework to my project, and i try to delete t and hope that flutter will generate it again but it not worked, and now i dont know how to generating App.framework in my ios/Flutter folder, and now the error that appears is : ld: framework not found App

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same Issue I am using VS Code on MacOs and I was experiencing same for Android

> Whenever you fresh run the project just type this command

```
flutter clean
```

Then

```
flutter run
```

Comment: I realized that this problem was caused by copying another App.framework to my project, and i try to delete t and hope that flutter will generate it again but it not worked, and now i dont know how to generating App.framework in my ios/Flutter folder, and now the error that appears is : ld: framework not found App